# UITableViewDiffableDataSource - animated transition of item while moving into another section

Tags: ios, swift, beta

**iOS 13 - beta**

I am using `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` and I want to move the item from one section into another.

I am applying a new snapshot to data source and item is moved instantly **without animated transition**. I have tried *.automatic* and *.fade* `defaultRowAnimation` for data source but no luck.

Automatic animation behaves very strangely.

I am thinking will it be properly animated if I use `UICollectionView` instead of `UITableView`?

Comment: UITableViewDiffableDataSource animations are broken at the moment, even an insert row doesn't animate properly (it animates away the last row then animates in again that row and the new one) https://twitter.com/malhal/status/1138737145408118784?s=20 I think they designed this API for UICollectionView and didn't test it with the table given in beta 1 the methods had the wrong generics: https://twitter.com/numist/status/1138622617437368321?s=20

Answer (score 0):

`NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot` has a method `moveItem(item,after/beforeItem)`.

After this method is called and snapshot is applied the moving transition is animated properly.

But, now there is a problem with unknown destination section. The method `moveItem` doesn't receive destination section parameter. So it is not clear in which section item will belong after transition.